# What does `gcloud compute instances create` do? - POST https://compute.googleapis.com…

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, reverse-engineering, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

Some things are very easy to do with the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) CLI, like:

```sh
$ export network='default' instance='example-instance' firewall='ssh-http-icmp-fw'
$ gcloud compute networks       create "$network"
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create "$firewall" --network "$network" \
                                                   --allow 'tcp:22,tcp:80,icmp'
$ gcloud compute instances      create "$instance" --network "$network" \
                                                   --tags 'http-server' \
                                                   --metadata \
  startup-script='#! /bin/bash
  # Installs apache and a custom homepage
  apt update
  apt -y install apache2
  cat <<EOF > /var/www/html/index.html
  <html><body><h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>This page was created from a start up script.</p>
  </body></html>'
$ # sleep 15s
$ curl $(gcloud compute instances list --filter='name=('"$instance"')' \
                                       --format='value(EXTERNAL_IP)')
```

(to be exhaustive in commands, tear down with)

```sh
$ gcloud compute networks       delete -q "$network"
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules delete -q "$firewall"
$ gcloud compute instances      delete -q "$instance"
```

…but it's not clear what the equivalent commands are from the REST API side. Especially considering the HUGE number of options, e.g., at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert

So I was thinking to just *steal* whatever `gcloud` does internally when I write my custom REST API client for Google Cloud's Compute Engine.

---

Running `rg` I found a bunch of these lines:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/b1a12d2/google/auth/transport/requests.py#L182

Specifically these 5 in `lib/third_party`:

```sh
google/auth/transport/{_aiohttp_requests.py,requests.py,_http_client.py,urllib3.py}
google_auth_httplib2/__init__.py
```

Below each of them I added `_LOGGER.debug("With body: %s", body)`. But there seems to be some [fancy batching](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/batch) going on because I almost never get that `With body` line

Now messing with Wireshark to see what I can find, but I'm confident this is a bad rabbit hole to fall down. Ditto for https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity.

---

How can I find out what body is being set by `gcloud`?

Comment: It does exactly what is says.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes but with what parameters? - How do I replicate it, say with `curl`?

Comment: Why on earth `curl`? `gcloud` obviously is not a HTTP resource.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - That's just an example. I'm writing a `gcloud compute` equivalent in C. All `gcloud compute` does is call https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1. This question is asking what parameters & body they are setting in their calls; and how to infer that.

Comment: Add the command line option `--log-http` to see the REST API parameters. There is no simple answer as the CLI changes over time. New features are added, removed, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks that looks like what I was seeking. Add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the command line option `--log-http` to see the REST API parameters.

There is no simple answer as the CLI changes over time. New features are added, removed, etc.