# Overcoming 401 on /compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, reverse-engineering, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

Reverse-engineering the `gcloud` tool—with [the suggested `--log-http`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67552756) mostly—I was able to get auth tokens generated, and even selected the same scope (double checking at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo):

```
http://[redacted]/callback?state=[redacted]&code=[redacted]&scope=email+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&authuser=0&prompt=consent

https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=[redacted]&redirect_uri=[redacted]/callback&client_id=[redacted]apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=[redacted]
```

Headers I try to hit the [`/zones/list` endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list) with:

```
Content-Type: application/json
charset: utf-8
Authorization: Bearer [redacted]
X-Goog-User-Project: [redacted]
```

I've also tried putting `access_token=[redacted]` in my query string. But not matter what I do, I always get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Other endpoints like like [`/projects/list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) seem to work with this access token (in header). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a support ticket, this looks like a bug, and I have a hunch that's related to some other issues I've been reading about these days.

Comment: Why are you **reverse-engineering**? There are so many examples on the Internet on how to do this in Python, C#, Java, C++, etc. The REST API is well documented. A quick Google search would have turned up a lot of examples. Example: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: @JohnHanley I was following the official REST API docs for Google Cloud Compute, but zones listing wouldn't work. So I tried with the `gcloud` CLI and it worked. So I started reverse-engineering exactly what they were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my original solution was 100% correct. For some odd reason the string being saved in the access token field of my struct was different to the one gathered from the remote auth flow.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from the error message, you got 401 http status code. It means that the access token you used does not give you access (is not authorised) to list zones. **And here you need to know that you cannot compare [zone.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list) and [projects.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list). In fact**:

- zone.list is part of compute engine API, whereas projects.list is part of resource-manager API
- zone.list requires `compute.zones.list` permission that is part of Compute Engine roles, like `Compute Viewer` whereas projects.list requires `resourcemanager.projects.list` which you'll find with many roles even the `Browser` role which is the smallest role (I think) in terms of number of permission.
- **To summarise, typically you used an access token of an identity which has access to projects.list but not to zone.list.** Example this identity has only `Browser` role.

Then, there this sentence that caught my attention on how you are getting the access token:

> Reverse-engineering the gcloud tool

You need to know that getting an access token is quite easy.

1. Run `gcloud auth login` which obtains access credentials for your user account via a web-based authorization flow.
2. Run `gcloud auth print-access-token` which prints an access token for your user account, so his permissions.

So if your user account has a role with `compute.zones.list` and `resourcemanager.projects.list` permissions (for example `Compute Viewer` role has both), you will be able to call both endpoints successfully.

Finally, here is a curl example, listing zones, using the generated access token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/zones
```

Comment: No I meant I was reverse-engineering it to be used on systems without `gcloud` installed. It's a C program which also runs a little server to handle the OAuth handshake. (it handles refresh tokens and access tokens). I just switched from custom socket-based HTTPS client to libcurl. The bit I'm confused about is why the `gcloud` token—found with `auth print-access-token`—is working, but my token; which has same scope specified; is not.